# image style using CSS or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to style image like this using `CSS`.

[image]

Comment: `img { // Style here }`

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Show some code and then ask why it isn't working, don't come here expecting people to do it for you

Comment: Probably don't need css, just put the img in html.

Answer (score 2):

What I think you wish to do is take an image and then mask out parts of it. You can achieve this through the combined used of svg and css.

First, you include an svg in the markup that defines a polygon that will be used for the clip-path (path needs to be vertically flipped or transformed with a matrix to account for the fact that top->bottom increases Y values in html coordinates, yet bottom->top increases Y values in svg)

The bounding-box for the clip-path is 0,0 325,205 and apparently, is fixed to absolute page coordinates. My demo works because the image is at the top left of the page. If the image moves, the clip-path doesn't,so you can easily get to a situation where the entirety of the image is outside the whole clip-path and you see nothing.

disclaimer: I really haven't investigated clip-paths much yet.

**EDIT**: This can also be done with pure css - the advantage being that coordinates can be expressed in percentages. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

### visualization of clip-path (in Inkscape)

[image]

Next, you set the clip-path using css and a reference to the (ID'd) path.

```css
img {
  width: 325px;
  height: 205px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipPath);
  clip-path: url(#clipPath);
}
.panel
{
 width: 325px;
 background-color: #f6f5f3;
 font-family: verdana;
}
.panel p, .panel h3
{
 margin: 4px 16px;
}
.panel h3
{
 font-size: 1.25em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class='panel'>
 <img src="http://previews.123rf.com/images/wavebreakmediamicro/wavebreakmediamicro1403/wavebreakmediamicro140343032/27149808-Portrait-of-university-students-with-laptop-lying-on-grass-on-college-campus-Stock-Photo.jpg" alt="" />
 <h3>Global Economic</h3>
 <p>Till the one day when the lady met this fellow
 and they knew it was much more than just a hunch</p>
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="clipPath">
   <polygon points="0.5 201 65 191 82 206 98 187 272 158 325 0.50 0.6 0.5"/>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style it using inline HTML: `<img style = "width:300px;height 300px;">`

OR

Using CSS (would have to create a separate document, which you would link to your HTML):

```
img{
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
```